# FileInfo.Exists Returns False after file is copied

Tags: c#-4.0

In the below code test.txt exists before it is run and test2.txt does not. When run destFile.Exists returns null after the file is copied to destFile's location. What is causing this? I cannot find any information in msdn that supports what is happening.

```
    var origFile = new FileInfo(@"C:\Users\user\Desktop\CopyTest\test.txt");
    var destFile = new FileInfo(@"C:\Users\user\Desktop\CopyTest\test2.txt");

    if (!destFile.Exists && origFile.Exists)
        origFile.CopyTo(destFile.FullName);

    if (destFile.Exists)
        Console.WriteLine("The file was found");

    Console.ReadLine();
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try to use [`destFile.Refresh();`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesysteminfo.refresh(v=vs.110).aspx) before you access the property

```
destFile.Refresh();
if (destFile.Exists)
        Console.WriteLine("The file was found");
```

or use the static method [`File.Exists`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.exists(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
if (File.Exists(@"C:\Users\user\Desktop\CopyTest\test2.txt"))
    Console.WriteLine("The file was found");
```

The `FileInfo` provides a lot of informations, but this is a snapshot which will be initialized the first time you access it and will not be updated later. So use it only if you need current state and if you need multiple informations. Otherwise use the [static methods in `System.IO.File`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file_methods(v=vs.110).aspx).

[Here](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/fileinfo.cs,1dcf92a404b7595d,references) you can see the current implementation of the `Exists` property. You see that it's initializing it the first time you access it, later the old state will be returned:

```
public override bool Exists {
[System.Security.SecuritySafeCritical]  // auto-generated
get {
    try {
        if (_dataInitialised == -1)
            Refresh();
        if (_dataInitialised != 0) {
            // Refresh was unable to initialise the data.
            // We should normally be throwing an exception here, 
            // but Exists is supposed to return true or false.
            return false;
        }
        return (_data.fileAttributes & Win32Native.FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY) == 0;
    }
    catch
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```